# How to access unc folder with current credentials without entering credentials info in c#?

Tags: c#, webdav, unc, networkcredentials

In my company I am developing an application with c# in which I have to access unc folder. I searched for this but came up with the examples where credentials need to be entered manually.

What I want to achieve is, there are two user groups(I don't know how IT department set them) one of which can't access the folder content. But can map the folder in Windows Explorer with credentials with empty content. Thus, as far as I understand it authenticates the user. So, I need to determine if the user has access or not. To do this, I am checking the content of the folder, if it is empty that means user don't have access if not he has. So far, the user needs to map the folder beforehand or program will throw authorization exception. Whether or not the user maps the folder, I want to get access to the current credential info without prompting any window to the user, since the one isn't set to have access to the content does not need to be prompted.

I have written something like this,

```
String pathWorkWebDav = "@\\domain@SSL\DavWWWRoot\folder";

Uri uri = new Uri(@"\\domain"); 
ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
var nc = credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
```

but don't know further.

**EDIT:**

I also tried [this,](http://www.mobilemotion.eu/?p=1582) but get the error as "Access to the path '\people.fev.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\personal\consulting' is denied." where my code section is like as follow;

How can I workaround this problem? I hope I am able to describe well.

```
String pathWorkWebDav = @"domain@SSL\DavWWWRoot\folder";
IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
var success = LogonUser("username", @"domain", "password",
            9, 0, ref token);
if (success)
{
   using (WindowsImpersonationContext person = new WindowsIdentity(token).Impersonate())
   {
      string[] allImgs = Directory.GetFiles(pathWorkWebDav);

      person.Undo();
      CloseHandle(token);
    }
}
```

Do I need to replace "username" and "passowrd" ? if so, this is not what I want.

Comment: *“but don't know further.”* — what's the actual problem? What error are you receiving?

Comment: It doesn't prompt an error. but I don't know how to use those credentials to access to unc folder. And how to check actual access write. Credentials have empty strings in username, domain and password properties.